# How can I (re)call function from within, without returning original call to sender

Tags: delphi

Here is an example of what I am trying to explain:

```
Var
NotDone:Boolean=False;

Function MyTestFunction:Boolean;
begin

 if NotDone<>True then
 begin
   NotDone:=True;
   MyTestFunction();
 end else
 begin
   Result:=True;
 end;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
NotDone:=False;

if mMyTestFunction=True then
begin
  ShowMessage('Returned: True');
end else
begin
   ShowMessage('Returned: False');
end;

end;
```

So I basically wants to call my function and under some circumstances "recall" from within, without main call (Code expression in button1 click) getting the result from the first call, then processing Second and returning that.

as you see I would have expected it to return true, but it returns false.

- How can I achieve my goal and or what is the best practice / Workarounds, that is NOT to write a duplicate of the function.

Comment: `if mMyTestFunction=True` is redundant because `if` always comes out as a `Boolean` type. Hence, `if mMyTestFunction` is enough - you're basically writing `if true=true` while `if true` is the same.

Comment: @AmigoJack Yes I am aware of that, I just thought, that,  in that "made up example", it would make more sence when reading it, to grasp what I intended to explain, as I struggled with forming a meaningfull sentence to describe it. But thank you anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as you see I would have expected it to return true, but it returns false.

Actually, the return value is undefined, as in the "NotDone<>True" case, you never assign any value to the Result of the call...

If I understand you correctly, wouldn't this do it:

```
Function MyTestFunction:Boolean;
begin

 if NotDone<>True then
 begin
   NotDone:=True;
   Result:=MyTestFunction();  // Return the value from second invokation
 end else
 begin
   Result:=True;
 end;

end;
```

Comment: Oh my gosh! How did I not think of this, seriously so simple and beautiful! I could not wrap my head around how that would work! Thank you so much mate! Have a nice day or night ahead!

Comment: @sea: Recursive programming (a function or procedure calling itself) is a concept that can be hard to grasp at first, but once you get it, the light bulb goes off, and it's suddenly evident :-) Remember to mark the answer as accepted and/or upvote it...

Comment: Totally! Many many lightbulps just went lit! -As fireworks on new years eve. It beat a philips hue bridge on Burst-Mode. Thank you, and accepted as awnser!

Comment: You do run the risk of a stack overflow here. Why use a recursive approach rather than iterative?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The code as listed is not susceptible to stack overflow, as "NotDone" is set to TRUE *before* calling MyTestFunction recursively, and the recursive call is only done if "NotDone" is NOT TRUE... But in all recursive calls, one must be aware of the risks of an infinite recursive call, leading to a Stack Overflow. I assume that the code listed was for illustrative purposes and not actual code. The actual code could be too complicated to implement iteratively (compared to recursive approach).

Comment: @HeartWare, yes you are correct, the actual code is much more complex but does follow the NotDone pricipal.